# How to change verbose code in Ruby to simpler code using Metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

It is said that Ruby is a metaprogramming language.  I wonder if the first 3 lines can be made less verbose using metaprogramming?

```
RUBY_VERSION ||= "unknown version"
RUBY_PATCHLEVEL ||= "unknown patchlevel"
RUBY_PLATFORM ||= "unknown platform"

print "Ruby ", RUBY_VERSION, " patch ", RUBY_PATCHLEVEL, " on ", RUBY_PLATFORM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the job:

```
%w{version patchlevel platform}.each{|v| eval "RUBY_#{v.upcase} ||= 'unknown #{v}'"}
```

but I think it's opaque and unpleasant. I think your original version is much better. In particular, I think `||=` with constants isn't great anyway (since constants shouldn't be dynamic), and that using `eval` with constants is not standard or therefore expected. Putting conditional assignment, constants and eval all together makes for a bad mix, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I think the original version is better too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't change value of constants. Instead try this:

```
puts "Ruby #{RUBY_VERSION || 'unknown version'}" # ...
```

Also, using Rails goodies, you could improve Peter's solution by calling

```
"RUBY_#{v}".constantize
```

instead of dirty `eval` ;-)